# Express - Not able to use multiple static folders for different routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, routes

I'm trying to show 2 different Angular 2 apps through Node/Express route.
But my route only shows only the root's index.html even on the path of other route. I tried a lot of different things but nothing seem to work. Would appreciate any help in this.

**UPDATE:**
I solved the problem by replacing these codes in **server.js**:

But now the issue is my route url shows like this "http://localhost:3020/iot/#./". I changed the LocationStrategy from **HashLocationStrategy** to **PathLocationStrategy** in app.module.ts but then the route doesn't work. How do I remove the '#' tags from my urls. If any one could suggest.

Hope my answer would help someone facing the same problem.

```
//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/client/dist/')));     
app.use('/mwc', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/mwc/dist/')));   

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/mwc', mwc);
app.use('/api/vi/', todos);
```

with just this

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use('/', express.static('client/dist'));
app.use('/mwc', express.static('mwc/dist'));
app.use('/iot', express.static('iot/dist'));
app.use('/canteen', express.static('canteen/dist'));
app.use('/api/vi/', todos);
```

& including the following code in my angular apps 'app.module.ts' & changing base href from "/" to "./" in index.html file.

```
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: './' },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
],
```

Below is the previous code:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var todos = require('./routes/todos');
var mwc = require('./routes/mwc');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();


//View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/client/dist/')));     
app.use('/mwc', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/mwc/dist/')));   

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/mwc', mwc);
app.use('/api/vi/', todos);

app.listen(3020, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3020...");
});
```

Comment: Why dont you just use different path. Like `/client` for first app and `/mwc` for second one

Comment: try to remove `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/client/dist/')));     
app.use('/mwc', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/mwc/dist/')));` or place them after you use your routes

Comment: I removed the above line of code but still it shows the same file on both the routes. I even gave the 'client' route as suggested by @UlrichDohou but still the same issue.